# Disable input (Angular)

Tags: angular, forms, disable

I need to set a value onInit and disable this input.
I tried something like this:

```
this.authenticationService.get().subscribe((user) => 
  this.form.controls.recruiter.setValue(`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`).disable()
);
```

but have error that `Property 'disable' does not exist on type 'void'.`
But If I rewrite it separately like this:

```
this.authenticationService.get().subscribe((user) => {
  this.form.controls.recruiter.setValue(`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`);
  this.form.controls.recruiter.disable();
});
```

the error is gone. Can someone explain why so and maybe there would be a better way how to make it.

Comment: setValue is used  to set the current formControl value dynamically and it's return nothing. disable method exist on formControl object, that's why you are getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variant didn't work because the [`setValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue) method returns nothing. So there would be no property to call the `disable()` function on.

If you need to be sure that the values are set before disabling it, you could try to subscribe to `valueChanges()` observable with `take(1)` operator piped in.

```js
this.authenticationService.get().pipe(
  switchMap((user) => {
    this.form.controls.recruiter.setValue(`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`);
    return this.form.controls.recruiter.valueChanges.pipe(take(1));
  }
).subscribe(
  null,
  null,
  () => { this.form.controls.recruiter.disable() }   // <-- trigger in `complete` callback to be sure
);
```